# My internet is slow since I installed Ubuntu

Tags: wireless, internet

I am an inexperienced Ubuntu user. Since I installed Ubuntu my Internet connection on this computer has become too slow.

Sometimes the internet connection gets disconnected or videos load slowly.

Here is my wireless information:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

##### release #####

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel #####

Linux andres-HP-14-Notebook-PC 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

##### lspci #####

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:218d]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8179] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:197d]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8188ee

##### lsusb #####

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b40d Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA Card Info #####

##### rfkill #####

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #####

rtl8188ee              89677  0 
rtl_pci                26690  1 rtl8188ee
rtlwifi                63475  2 rtl_pci,rtl8188ee
mac80211              630653  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8188ee
cfg80211              484040  2 mac80211,rtlwifi

##### iw reg get #####

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

##### interfaces #####

# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### iwconfig #####

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"JANET PC"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: <MAC address removed>   
          Bit Rate=150 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-14 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:5   Missed beacon:0

##### route #####

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.2     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0

##### resolv.conf #####

nameserver 127.0.1.1
search espol.edu.ec

##### nm-tool #####

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: wlan0  [JANET PC] ----------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            rtl8188ee
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC address removed>

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           150 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
    RIOFRIO:         Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 27 WPA WPA2
    LORENCES CARDENAS: Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 100 WPA WPA2
    TVCABLE CARLOS:  Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2452 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 54 WPA WPA2
    Familia Velasquez : Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 48 Mb/s, Strength 60 WEP
    ZyXEL:           Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 60
    ZHIRZHAN AZANZA: Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 27 WPA2
    red Barrezueta:  Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 100 WPA
    *JANET PC:       Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 74 WPA WPA2

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.1.104
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.1.2

    DNS:             192.168.1.2

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC address removed>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off

##### NetworkManager.state #####

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf #####

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

no-auto-default=<MAC address removed>,

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### iwlist #####

wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC address removed>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=64/70  Signal level=-46 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"JANET PC"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000000f53f342
                    Extra: Last beacon: 4ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 00084A414E4554205043
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B960C121824
                    IE: Unknown: 03010B
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 32043048606C
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101850003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: DD1E00904C334E111BFF00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1A4E111BFF00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD1A00904C340B0F0800000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D160B0F0800000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD0900037F01010000FF7F
                    IE: Unknown: DD0A00037F04010000004000
                    IE: Unknown: DD850050F204104A0001101044000102103B0001031047001000000000000010000000F8D1114C7EEC1021000754502D4C494E4B10230009544C2D57523734304E10240007312E302F322E3010420003312E301054000800060050F204000110110019576972656C65737320526F7574657220544C2D57523734304E100800020086103C000101
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC address removed>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=48/70  Signal level=-62 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"LORENCES CARDENAS"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000092627030f
                    Extra: Last beacon: 4ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 00114C4F52454E4345532043415244454E4153
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B960C121824
                    IE: Unknown: 03010B
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 32043048606C
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101850003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: DD1E00904C334E111BFF00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1A4E111BFF00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD1A00904C340B0F0A00000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D160B0F0A00000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD0900037F01010000FF7F
                    IE: Unknown: DD0A00037F04010000004000
                    IE: Unknown: DD850050F204104A0001101044000102103B0001031047001000000000000010000000F8D1114C58D01021000754502D4C494E4B10230009544C2D57523734304E10240007312E302F322E3010420003312E301054000800060050F204000110110019576972656C65737320526F7574657220544C2D57523734304E100800020086103C000101

##### iwlist channel #####

wlan0     13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)

##### modinfo #####

filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8188ee/rtl8188ee.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8188efw.bin
description:    Realtek 8188E 802.11n PCI wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.Finger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         zhiyuan_yang    <zhiyuan_yang@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     FA356D8EFD887B567263405
alias:          pci:v000010ECd00008179sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        rtlwifi,rtl_pci,mac80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        <MAC address removed>:65:43:53:5F:A2:BB:5B:70:9E:84:F1:6D:A7:C7
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           swenc:Set to 1 for software crypto (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           ips:Set to 0 to not use link power save (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           swlps:Set to 1 to use SW control power save (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           fwlps:Set to 1 to use FW control power save (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           msi:Set to 1 to use MSI interrupts mode (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           debug:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)

filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl_pci.ko
description:    PCI basic driver for rtlwifi
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     D5E4890DC428FA5A1BF92DF
depends:        mac80211,rtlwifi
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        <MAC address removed>:65:43:53:5F:A2:BB:5B:70:9E:84:F1:6D:A7:C7
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko
description:    Realtek 802.11n PCI wireless core
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     E1F4663325225EE8DBA54CA
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        <MAC address removed>:65:43:53:5F:A2:BB:5B:70:9E:84:F1:6D:A7:C7
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

##### modules #####

lp
rtc

----------


    ##### blacklist #####

    [/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
    blacklist ath_pci

    [/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
    blacklist evbug
    blacklist usbmouse
    blacklist usbkbd
    blacklist eepro100
    blacklist de4x5
    blacklist eth1394
    blacklist snd_intel8x0m
    blacklist snd_aw2
    blacklist i2c_i801
    blacklist prism54
    blacklist bcm43xx
    blacklist garmin_gps
    blacklist asus_acpi
    blacklist snd_pcsp
    blacklist pcspkr
    blacklist amd76x_edac

    [/etc/modprobe.d/fbdev-blacklist.conf]
    blacklist arkfb
    blacklist aty128fb
    blacklist atyfb
    blacklist radeonfb
    blacklist cirrusfb
    blacklist cyber2000fb
    blacklist gx1fb
    blacklist gxfb
    blacklist kyrofb
    blacklist matroxfb_base
    blacklist mb862xxfb
    blacklist neofb
    blacklist nvidiafb
    blacklist pm2fb
    blacklist pm3fb
    blacklist s3fb
    blacklist savagefb
    blacklist sisfb
    blacklist tdfxfb
    blacklist tridentfb
    blacklist viafb
    blacklist vt8623fb

    ##### udev rules #####

    # PCI device 0x10ec:0x8136 (r8169)
    SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address removed>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

    # PCI device 0x10ec:0x8179 (rtl8188ee)
    SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address removed>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

    ##### dmesg #####

    [   10.240208] rtl8188ee: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8188efw.bin
    [   10.479355] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
    [   10.479708] rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
    [   18.747581] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
    [   18.751540] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
    [   20.957674] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
    [   20.977605] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
    [   20.980598] wlan0: authenticated
    [   20.981173] wlan0: associate with <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
    [   20.984873] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address removed> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
    [   20.984992] wlan0: associated
    [   20.985028] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
    [   21.034651] wlan0: deauthenticating from <MAC address removed> by local choice (reason=2)
    [   21.068107] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
    [   21.461735] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
    [   22.821096] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 2/3)
    [   22.826304] wlan0: authenticated
    [   22.829090] wlan0: associate with <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
    [   22.833971] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address removed> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
    [   22.834098] wlan0: associated
    [   54.012122] wlan0: Connection to AP <MAC address removed> lost
    [   55.405663] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
    [   55.425482] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
    [   55.429380] wlan0: authenticated
    [   55.433055] wlan0: associate with <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
    [   55.436758] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address removed> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
    [   55.436882] wlan0: associated
    [  583.627809] wlan0: Connection to AP <MAC address removed> lost
    [  585.033994] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
    [  585.055689] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
    [  585.156727] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 2/3)
    [  585.260717] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 3/3)
    [  585.364768] wlan0: authentication with <MAC address removed> timed out
    [  598.385936] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
    [  598.405598] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
    [  598.407041] wlan0: authenticated
    [  598.408993] wlan0: associate with <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
    [  598.413122] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address removed> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
    [  598.413249] wlan0: associated
    [  616.462662] wlan0: deauthenticating from <MAC address removed> by local choice (reason=3)
    [  617.405492] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
    [  617.425021] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
    [  617.457648] wlan0: deauthenticating from <MAC address removed> by local choice (reason=3)
    [  618.310553] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
    [  618.329456] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
    [  618.332790] wlan0: authenticated
    [  618.336698] wlan0: associate with <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
    [  618.337996] wlan0: deauthenticating from <MAC address removed> by local choice (reason=3)
    [  618.340764] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address removed> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
    [  618.340892] wlan0: associated
    [  618.341374] wlan0: deauthenticating from <MAC address removed> by local choice (reason=3)
    [  619.209225] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
    [  619.229031] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
    [  619.230520] wlan0: authenticated
    [  619.236696] wlan0: associate with <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
    [  619.245231] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address removed> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
    [  619.245352] wlan0: associated
    [  619.257092] wlan0: deauthenticating from <MAC address removed> by local choice (reason=2)
    [  619.297362] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address removed>
    [  619.307555] wlan0: send auth to <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
    [  619.309417] wlan0: authenticated
    [  619.312712] wlan0: associate with <MAC address removed> (try 1/3)
    [  619.316434] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC address removed> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
    [  619.316561] wlan0: associated

    ########## wireless info END ############
```

Any sort of assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is the first part of the information? it is missing.

Comment: Sorry, I have some troubles editing the text so it can be readable, this is my first post

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would suggest getting off that channel (2462). There's like 4 people using that in your area and you're most likely suffering from interference issues. You're at channel 11 (2462) and channel 1 (2412) looks pretty congested as well so pick a channel like 3, 4, 7, 8 or 10.

Do this through your wireless router settings.

[image]
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels

Answer (score 0):

Try to run a test against DSLReports.com and see if they measure an issue with the connection, preferably compare to a different computer also running on your network. This will diagnose if there is a genuine issue with the specific computer.

It's entirely possible there's some Wifi driver issue. Those problems do occur on occasion.